# Are primes in arithmetic sequences equally prevalent in the limit?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic-progressions

It's clear that some arithmetic sequences start off much more prime-dense than others, e.g. $6x+1$ compared to, say, $7x+13$.

As $x \rightarrow \infty$, do all arithmetic sequences even out in terms of the proportion of primes they yield, or do the ones that start out strong maintain an edge forever?

And if there is an established answer to this, does it also apply to quadratic primes, like e.g. $x^2+1$ being more prime-ful than $x^2+17$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_bias

Comment: In the limit, doesn't that race switch back and forth infinitely many times?

Comment: Yes. To quote the Wikipedia page that Angina linked to:

*The stronger conjecture of Knapowski and Turán, that the density of the numbers x for which π(x; 4, 3) > π(x; 4, 1) holds is 1 (i.e. π(x; 4, 3) > π(x; 4, 1) holds for almost all x), turned out to be false. They, however, do have a logarithmic density, which is approximately 0.9959....*

Comment: On a vaguely related note, among the first billion primes, if a prime ends in the digit $9$ then the last digit of the next prime is $65$% more likely to be a $1$ than a $9$. https://www.quantamagazine.org/mathematicians-discover-prime-conspiracy-20160313/

Comment: You might also be interested in https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prime-GeneratingPolynomial.html.